# How do I write a Clojure Spec for a function that takes a sequence argument?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I'm writing a function that takes a sequence of Triangles (which are in fact represented as `maps`).

My spec is :

```
(s/fdef triangle-list-to-pattern
        :args (s/cat :trs (s/* ::maths/Triangle))
        )
```

And the function takes a single argument, trs which is a sequence of Triangles.

However, when I instrument this function and call it I get the following failure :

```
fails spec: :patterning.maths/Triangle at: [:args :trs] predicate: map?
```

If I explicitly test the argument I'm passing to the function with spec, it passes. It really is just a sequence of things that meet the Triangle criteria.

The function seems to be working. The argument seems to be correct, and passes the spec when tested separately. So I presume I'm getting the `fdef` wrong somehow.

What's the problem?

Note, ::Triangle is defined :

```
(s/def ::Triangle (s/keys :req-un [::A ::B ::C ::a ::b ::c ::ax ::ay ::bx ::by ::cx ::cy]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your `:args` spec isn't working is that [*regex* specs](https://www.clojure.org/guides/spec#_sequences) compose to describe a single sequence when nested.

You can escape this behavior by wrapping your inner regex spec `s/*` in `s/spec`:

```
(s/cat :trs (s/spec (s/* ::maths/Triangle)))
```

Or use a different, non-regex spec to describe the sequence argument:

```
(s/cat :trs (s/coll-of ::maths/Triangle))
```

Your example spec *would* work if your function was variadic, because `s/cat` and `s/*` are composing to describing a single sequence with zero or more elements.

```
(defn adder [& nums] (apply + nums))
(s/fdef adder :args (s/cat :nums (s/* int?)))
(st/instrument `adder)
(adder 1 2 3)
```

Comment: Ah ... that's it. Thanks. 

That was driving me mad because I couldn't see anything wrong with what I was doing.

Comment: Thanks, that was useful for me too :)